# Как расположить div'ы разного размера так рядом так, чтобы они заполняли все свободное пространство?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, выравнивание

Есть условно 20 дивов, ширина у всех одинакова, но высота разная. Они идут в ряд, и когда начинается новая строка блоков, они оставляют пустые места над собой и идут по линии, выравниваясь по верхней грани. Как сделать заполнение всех свободных мест, если это возможно?
Прикладываю скрин. Нужно чтобы News 25, News 26 поднялись выше, заполнив пустое пространство, а не выравнивались все по одной высоте.
Результат должен быть похож на подобие "стикеров", пусть и с одинаковым марджином, но с разной позиционкой, более хаотичной.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что хотел бы получить: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заполнение автоматическое, и нужно чтобы между блоками не было пустого пространства. Они все еще идут в ряд, но при этом если сверху есть место - он поднимется выше. Можно как-то через столбцы, но не понимаю как. Ширина у всех одинаковая.

Comment: Если условно, то так - [align-items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items#result)

Comment: делай колонки, а не строки

Comment: @UModeL, а как тут align-items поможет?

Comment: @Grundy, думаю, что значением _stretch_

Comment: @UModeL, тогда будет искажение карточек ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ тут скорее поможет [grid-auto-flow:dense](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow) но нужен пример разметки и ожидаемого результата

Comment: Добавь пример разметки и ожидание как это должно выглядеть в итоге.

Comment: @Grundy, о том и речь - "нужен пример разметки и ожидаемого результата". Но, чую, что без _Masonry_ проблема не решится.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, предоставив пример.

Comment: @Surion это пример того, как сейчас, нужен пример того как это должно выглядеть

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, дописав как должно выглядеть) Новость 25 и 26 должны быть выше, тк там есть свободное место. Должен быть эффект хаоса, как стикеры разной длинны налепленные на стену.

Comment: @Surionm да, не увидел этот текст, только картинку с дырками. Высота как-то ограничена контейнера? Или она растет вниз по мере добавления элементов?

Comment: @Grundy Ограничена, где-то раза в 1.5 больше может быть минимлаьного, а дальше скролл появляется. Но это не обязательное условие, его можно подправить как угодно.

Comment: скролл куда? у какого элемента?

Comment: @Grundy У всех элементов, у которых контент больше дефолтного. Мин высота новости - 100пикселей, макс - 150, дальше скролл.

Comment: не, речь шла по контейнер где список новостей лежит. Можно разделить на колонки либо flex-direction: column, но тут нужно будет ограничивать высоту чтобы он знал когда следующую колонку делать, и направление элементов будет не слева направо, а сверху вниз

Answer (score 1):

вроде то что надо

**UPD:**

- добавил хаоса
- чекбокс включил для ясности, что это именно чекбокс а не какой то квадратик...)

**UPD 2:**

- добавил выключенных чекбоксов и раскидал разные спаны по ним для наглядности

```css
#x{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(18, 1fr);
grid-auto-rows: 1.5em;
grid-auto-flow: dense;
grid-gap: .5em;
}


li{
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  list-style: integer inside;
}


#x *{grid-area: span 2 / span 2;}
/* щепотка хаоса по вкусу... */
#a:checked ~ :nth-child(7n -3){
grid-area: span 3 / span 2;
background: gold;}

#b:checked ~ :nth-child(11n -10){grid-area: span 4 / span 3}
#c:checked ~ :nth-child(11n -9){grid-area: span 3 / span 1;}
#d:checked ~ :nth-child(11n -8){grid-column: span 1;}
#e:checked ~ :nth-child(11n -5){grid-row: span 3;}
#f:checked ~ :nth-child(11n -6){grid-column: span 3;}
#g:checked ~ :nth-child(11n -4){grid-row: span 4;}
#h:checked ~ :nth-child(11n -7){grid-column: span 4;}
#i:checked ~ :nth-child(11n -2){grid-area: span 1 / span 2;}
#j:checked ~ :nth-child(11n -1){grid-area: span 3 / span 3;}
#k:checked ~ :nth-child(11n){grid-area: span 1 / span 1;}
```

```html
<ol id='x'>
<input type='checkbox' id='a' checked>
<input type='checkbox' id='b'>
<input type='checkbox' id='c'>
<input type='checkbox' id='d'>
<input type='checkbox' id='e'>
<input type='checkbox' id='f'>
<input type='checkbox' id='g'>
<input type='checkbox' id='h'>
<input type='checkbox' id='i'>
<input type='checkbox' id='j'>
<input type='checkbox' id='k'>

  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: у тебя все элементы получились одинаковой высоты - а на картинке в вопросе - `news21` явно выше чем соседние

Comment: а, все, не увидел что там галочка есть - но тут в любом случае высоты выравниваются, конкретно у тебя до двух строк. Есть подозрение, что это не совсем то, что нужно

Comment: @Grundy, ну... никто ведь не запрещает наплодить вариантов - `.w{span 2} .x{span 3} .y{span .5} .z{span .25} ....` неужели все по буквам надо писать... и да, я понимаю что хотелось бы большей гибкости, но span auto не сработал, а dense только с переростками прибитыми к конкретным линиям работает так как хочется, увы. можно конечно еще флексы попробовать, но вангую там будут проблемки с количеством столбцов !>2. а columns если память не изменяет вообще не контейнеры а сам контент делит, так что вот так...

Comment: фактически эти варианты равносильны ручному выстраиванию сетки. dense по сути сейчас точно так же работает. В идеале будет с [grid-template-rows: masonry;](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/native-css-masonry-layout-css-grid/#the-masonry-feature-of-grid-layout) но пока это нигде не поддерживается, а в firefox частично, с флагом

Comment: @Grundy, да нет, не совсем так же. для dense нужно именно отдельно каждого ребенка растягивать по сетке(указывать каждому отдельные не занятые кем то еще координаты, иначе все в одну стопку на z оси схлопнутся). можно конечно вывернуться с указыванием как минимум двух видов классов каждому ребенку(x & y координаты по сути) и уже в css что то типа `.codrs-x{row-start: 3}, .cords-y{column-end: 5}...` чуете каким трешем пахнет? для готового макета где некоторые блоки уже прибиты к своим местам да, dense шикарен, но на скрине явно какая то **выдача списка новостей, там все блоки генерируются**

Comment: @Grundy, впрочем в чем то вы правы... дополнил для ясности.

Comment: @puffleeck Да, новости в форму пишутся и добавляются автоматом. Решение со столбцами кажется интересным, ширина ведь одинаковая у всех, но как реализовать заполнение столбцов так, будто они в ряд? Мне кажется это возможно если запариться, считывать колво дивов в 1 ряду, например 5, будет 5 столбцов по 1 диву. С появлением 6 кинуть его в 1 столбец, 7 - во 2, но кроме как реализовать это через медиа запросы с макс-шириной и пахнущей говнокодом сложной функции, выдающей классы, мне в голову не приходит. Я учусь, и в шоке что нет простой строчки ксс кода, решающей вопрос. Это странно.

Comment: @Surion, нет простой строчки кода потому, что на самом деле это не так уж и просто сделать. Ну и ты всегда можешь воспользоваться абсолютным позиционирование и js

Comment: @Surion, `например 5, будет 5 столбцов по 1 диву. С появлением 6 кинуть его в 1 столбец, 7 - во 2` нуууу... grid именно так изначально и работает... снимите галочку и увидите результат без `:nth-child`а. `заполнение столбцов так, будто они в ряд?` всмысле?... в сочетании с исходным недовольством пустотами, мне кажется вам просто надо обрезку блоков "переростков" реализовать. если нет, посидите с листом и ручкой над формулировкой желаемого - **полноценно сформулированный вопрос** это половина ответа и часто именно его отсутствие(полноценного вопроса) главное препятствие к ответу.

Comment: @Surion или может дорисуйте хотя бы в банальном paint'е до такого состояния, которое хотите получить

Comment: @puffleeck Дорисовал, обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Surion, дополнил. ну как дополнил... просто выключил лишние варианты, чекбоксы поклацайте и все поймете...)

Answer (score 1):

Нативное решение - использование [columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns). Конечно, есть один существенный недостаток - это неравномерность заполнения колонок, что хорошо заметно по нижнему краю. Из плюсов: адаптивность, минимум кода и настроек, отсутствие скриптов и сторонних ресурсов.

```js
/* Скрипт нужен только для сокращения HTML-разметки в текущем примере */
const LIST = document.querySelector('.news_list');
for (let i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
  LIST.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
  <div class="news_item">
    <div class="news_title">News ${i}</div>
    <div class="news_text"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/240/160?lock=${Math.floor(Math.random() * 30000 + 1)}">${'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Amet, rem fugit. Atque, quo quae quos? Doloribus odit quis vitae nisi culpa totam, hic ab aut nobis eos, ipsam est. '.repeat(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1))}</div>
    <div class="news_author">Author: <span>admin</span></div>
  </div>
  `)
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; min-height: 100vh; background-color: #f2eaed; }

.news_list {
  padding: 20px 10px 0;
  /* Собственно сами колонки */
  column-width: 300px;
  column-gap: 30px;
}

.news_item {
  margin-bottom: 2.5em;
  border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  border-radius: .66em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 12px/1.8em sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.news_title {
  padding: 1.8em 1.5em 1em;
  font: bold 1.4em/1em sans-serif;
}

.news_text {
  min-height: 10em;
  padding: 0 2.1em 1.3em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 1em/1.8em sans-serif;
}

.news_text > img {
  float: right;
  height: 8em;
  aspect-ratio: 3 / 2;
  padding: .5em 0 0 .75em;
}

.news_author {
  padding: 2em;
  font: 1em/1em sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  color: #565a5c;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

```html
<div class="news_list"></div>
```

Comment: и направление - сверху вниз, по колонкам, а не слева направо

Comment: @Grundy, хаос в _новостях_ не приветствуется, а если это не _новости_, то порядок не имеет сильной значимости, как по мне. Поверьте, вопрошающий придёт к этому рано или поздно, но нам в этом не признается ;-)

Comment: Ага, еще и  отсортировать случайно :)