# Css grid Как создать

Tags: css, css3, grid, css-grid

проломал голову уже часов 6, не получается сверстать блок. А именно друг под друга поставить могу, но чтобы фото занимали пустое пространство не получается(
Заранее спасибо)

[image: css grid | блок с картинками]

Comment: На данный момент (март 2024) нет возможности сделать полноценный `masonry layout` на `grid`. Работы над соответствующей спецификацией ведутся. А пока вы можете воспользоваться решением на js - https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: эффект ламината... рекомендую заглянуть сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1554376/ ничего приличнее имеющихся там двух вариантов пока на ум не приходит...